# Solving for a variable that's raised to some arbitrary exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve the following equation in terms of $q_1$?

$c_1 = a - b((q_1 + q_2)^d + (d * q_1 * (q_1 + q_2)^g))$

$g = d-1$

Nothing algebraically seems to work, and I tried using logarithms as well, but that didn't work either.

Comment: This is precalc? Seems a bit nasty in terms of solving for $q_1$. Looking at the equation it seems likely to be some kind of secant? The second term is the derivative of the first term with regards to $q_2$. Are you sure you can't use something other method than solving for $q_1$? Just trying out $d=1$ and $d=2$ gives very different answers. While I can't say for sure there won't be a nice closed form solution it seems rather unlikely. But maybe there is some clever trick without using calc or series.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a way to solve this without calculus, so I used calculus. The equation is
$c_1=a-b(q_1+q_2)^{d}+q_1d(q_1+q_2)^{d-1}$

If you let $y(q_1)=(q_1+q_2)^d$, the equation is transformed to

$c_1=a-by(q_1)+q_1y'(q_1)$, which can be rearranged as $y'(q_1)-\cfrac{b}{q_1}y(q_1)=\cfrac{c_1-a}{q_1}$

The integrating factor for this differential equation is $e^{\int\cfrac{-b}{q_1}dq_1}=q_1^{-b}$, so

$[q_1^{-b}y(q_1)]'=(c_1-a)q_1^{1-b}$

$q_1^{-b}y(q_1)=\cfrac{c_1-a}{-b}q_1^{-b}+c_2$

$y(q_1)=\cfrac{a-c_1}{b}+c_2q_1^b$

Substituting back in, we get $(q_1+q_2)^d=\cfrac{a-c_1}{b}+c_2q_1^b$

Setting $q_1=1$, this gives $c_2=(1+q_2)^d+\cfrac{c_1-a}{b}$

If this is zero, the solution is pretty simple. Otherwise, its not. Are there any extra pieces of information in this question?

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$q_1+q_2 = u,
q_2 = v,
c_1 = c$.

Then
$c_1 
= a - b((q_1 + q_2)^d + (d * q_1 * (q_1 + q_2)^g))
$
becomes

$\begin{array}\\
c 
&= a - b(u^d + (d (u-v)u^{d-1}))\\
&= a - b(u^d + d (u-v)u^{d-1})\\
&= a - b(u^d + d u^{d}-d vu^{d-1})\\
&= a - b(u^d(1+d)-d vu^{d-1})\\
&= a - bu^{d-1}(u(1+d)-d v)\\
\text{or}\\
\dfrac{a-c}{b}
&= u^{d-1}(u(1+d)-d v)\\
\end{array}
$

This is an equation
of degree $d$ in $u$.
This can be easily solved if
$d \le 2$,
messily solved if
$3 \le d \le 4$,
and not solvable in general
if $d \ge 5$.

If you know something
about the variables,
that might help.